# Django convention for naming a ForeignKey that uses the to_field param?

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, relational-database

I'm wondering if there is a convention for naming a foreign key field in Django that is mapped to another field with `to_field`. For example, should the Django field name be the model name and the database field name be the column name or is that confusing?

```
class Stations(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    observations = models.ForeignKey(Observations, 
                                     to_field='zone_code'
                                     db_column='zone_code')

class Observations(models.Model):
    zone_code = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    metric_a = models.IntegerField()
    metric_a = models.IntegerField()
```

It doesn't really make sense to have this:

```
class Stations(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    observations = models.ForeignKey(Observations, 
                                     to_field='zone_code')

class Observations(models.Model):
    zone_code = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    metric_a = models.IntegerField()
    metric_a = models.IntegerField()
```

nor this

```
class Stations(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    zone_code = models.ForeignKey(Observations, 
                                     to_field='zone_code')

class Observations(models.Model):
    zone_code = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    metric_a = models.IntegerField()
    metric_a = models.IntegerField()
```

because then you end up with `observations_id` or `zone_code_id` when the column in the database is actually the zone_code. Anyone have this issue before?

Comment: What's the problem with your first version? You are mapping to a `Oberservations` object so naming it `observations` is clear and concise. `to_field` merely describes which field you use for identifying the related object but that's a different story. It's still a `Observations` object.

Comment: Just trying to verify the convention. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Include other field as choices to foreign key, Django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43906504/include-other-field-as-choices-to-foreign-key-django)